# JQuery-ui autocomplete feature with id and value in response, but how to display value in autocomplete text box and id in hiddenbox text

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am getting Spring JPA response in below format

```
[
    [12, "companyReferenceNumber1"],
    [13, "companyReferenceNumber2"],
    [14, "companyReferenceNumber3"],
    [15, "companyReferenceNumber4"],
    [16, "companyReferenceNumber5"],
    [17, "companyReferenceNumber6"],
    [18, "companyReferenceNumber7"],
    [19, "companyReferenceNumber8"],
    [20, "companyReferenceNumber9"],
    [21, "companyReferenceNumber10"]
]
```

and reaching towards ajax -> success -> **data** parameter
now I wanted to show only value in autocomplete text box and key in hidden. Tried all the ways to do it, but I may be missing some small thing somewhere. A little look and help on my code will be truly helpful. Stuck since 4 days now.

```js
//Adding JQuery code

$("#employeeId").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/searchEmployeeId",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.name
          };
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) { //Error here : ReferenceError: item is not defined
    $("#employeeId").val(ui.item[1]);
    $("#empId").val(ui.item[0]);
    alert(ui.item + "d");
    return false;
  },
  change: function(event, ui) {
    $("#employeeId").val(ui.item ? ui.item.value : 0);
  },
  minLength: 2
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow it started working. Below is the solution. Will keep updating if I have any updates.

```js
$("#employeeId").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/searchEmployeeId",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item[1],
            value: item[0]
          };
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#employeeId").val(ui.item.label);
    $("#empId").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
  },
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $("#employeeId").val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  },
  change: function(event, ui) {
    $("#employeeId").val(ui.item ? ui.item.label : 0);
  },
  minLength: 2
});
$("#employeeId").autocomplete("option", "appendTo", ".eventInsForm");
```